# On the distances on the earth's Surface as seen from a spatial external observer in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, acceleration

Recently I was thinking about general relativity, I was wondering what distances would look like on the earth's surface seen from outer space, according to general relativity time passes more slowly on the earth's surface, let suposse there are two systems of reference, one in the earth standing on the ground, a person and a mirror located less than two meters from the person, and one in the space, a geostationary Astronaut, then, if the person used a flashlight to illuminate the mirror horizontally and paralell to the planet's Surface, I thought that the distance that the light must travel for the external observer must be longer than the distance that the illuminator sees in his reference system, because if time passes more slowly seen by a spatial observer in a inertial system then what the observer sees is for example, a distance of two meters from the person to the mirror, instead who is on the earth's ground sees less than two meters for the light to travel to arrive the mirror, the Astronaut thinks that the light on the earth is also stretched and changes frequency and the speed is 300000km/s, while for the one on the ground its frequency does not Vary and speed is also 300000km/s, is it due to this stretching in space and time dilation that light travels longer distances as seen on earth from space?

Answer (score 1):

These arguments so successfully made in STR fall apart in GR. While in STR any inertial observer defines global frame, this is not so in GR. In GR, frames are only local, so talking about some distant process being seen from some frame is,  strictly speaking, meaningless. One of the issues is, that due to the curvature of spacetime, distant observer doesn't really know which distant events he is supposed to consider to be simultaneous with events on his worldline.

That being said, geometry around planets is usually well approximated by Schwarzschild metric, which has enough symmetries to put up a physically meaningful global coordinate system that can be interpreted as frame of distant observer. In particular, the symmetries allow him to distinguish distant events by claiming which of them are simultaneous with his worldline. This allows him to have his own opinion on how long some distant process is happening by looking at the events on his worldline that are simultaneous with bounding events of the process in question.

The metric is $$ds^2=-(1-\frac{r_s}{r})c^2 dt^2+(1-\frac{r_s}{r})^{-1}dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2 +\sin^2\theta d\phi^2),$$
$r_s$ being Schwarzschild radius.

The meaningful coordinates of distant observer are these $t$ and $r$ coordinates called Schwarzschild coordinates. As you can see, the metric in this coordinates does not depend on time $t$, so there is a preferred global time in this particular case and this preferred global time reduces to the proper time of observer infinitely distant from the planet and at rest with it. There is also preferred radial coordinate $r$ in which the angular part of metric looks like we are in a flat space.

When we are talking about distances, we are really talking about simultaneous events so the distance between mirror and person on Earth is (assuming they are close enough together for us to ignore integration) $$d^2 = (1+\frac{r_s}{r})^{-1}d'^2,$$
where $d$ is locally measured distance, i.e. distance according to the person on the Earth, while $d'$ is coordinate distance, in this case the distance according to the distant observer.

This is in vertical direction, in horizontal one you would get $$d=d'$$ since angular part is the same as in the flat space.

As you see, it does not depend on gravitational time dilation, only on spatial curvature, since we were interested in simultaneous events.

Your thought experiment with mirror is not useful for this case though. It is made in STR because one of the axioms of STR is that we can look at the experiment from two points of view a priori. We then use reasoning about results of such an experiment and about how the two views are connected.

But in GR, since we cannot look at distant processes and have our own opinion, we cannot reason about result of the experiment and how the two views (one of which does not exist) are connected. We first need to probe spacetime by local measurements to find out the metric and only then we can define the other point of view. Having the metric though, we can just use it directly without such roundabouts.

In STR we could also start by writing down the minkowski metric and forget about mirror thought experiment. But this is less intuitive approach so we often prefer the thought experiment one. I mean, writing down minkowski metric straight at the beginning, while logically equivalent to traditional axioms of STR, would look like magic to newcomers, while axioms about invariance of light speed and relativity principle seem more natural.

Comment: Outstanding, I will see it on special theory, althoug I think a gravitatory or non inertial frame it is not inapropiate because there are experiments where for example we can meassure the redshift effect on light standing outside the earth, but your point of view is very professional and accurate, so to apply this case on STR two accelerated frames are needed, uniform acceleration for the Astronaut and non uniform for the person and the mirror(a rocket for example), but both systems must be stationary within each other, that is the third frame needed

Comment: I understand the Schwarzschild metric, it is used to estimate the simultaneity of events based on the precise geometry of space-time, it is like a reference point on which to base yourself, interesting idea, That looks like a multi variable differential equation